# Installing Font VB

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I have a working code that installs the font but not permanently and can't be seen in the fonts list in control panel. So how to install fonts permanently programmatically?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
If Not CustomFont.IsFontInstalled("Monotype Corsiva") = True Then
    Dim FontPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\Monotype Corsiva.ttf"
    Dim Ret As Integer
    Dim Res As Integer
    Const WM_FONTCHANGE As Integer = &H1D
    Const HWND_BROADCAST As Integer = &HFFFF
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(FontPath, My.Resources.Monotype_Corsiva)
    Ret = AddFontResource(FontPath)
    Res = SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0)
    Ret = WriteProfileString("fonts", "Monotype Corsiva (TrueType)", "Monotype Corsiva.ttf")
    MsgBox("Font installed")
End If
```

And here is the module:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Module CustomFont
    <DllImport("gdi32")>
    Public Function AddFontResource(ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Public Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Function WriteProfileString(ByVal lpszSection As String, ByVal lpszKeyName As String, ByVal lpszString As String) As Integer
    End Function
    'PRIVATE FONT COLLECTION TO HOLD THE DYNAMIC FONT
    Private _pfc As PrivateFontCollection = Nothing
    Public ReadOnly Property GetInstance(ByVal Size As Single, ByVal style As FontStyle) As Font
        Get
            'IF THIS IS THE FIRST TIME GETTING AN INSTANCE
            'LOAD THE FONT FROM RESOURCES
            If _pfc Is Nothing Then LoadFont()

            'RETURN A NEW FONT OBJECT BASED ON THE SIZE AND STYLE PASSED IN
            Return New Font(_pfc.Families(0), Size, style) ',Style
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Sub LoadFont()
        Try
            'INIT THE FONT COLLECTION
            _pfc = New PrivateFontCollection
            'LOAD MEMORY POINTER FOR FONT RESOURCE
            Dim fontMemPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(My.Resources.Monotype_Corsiva.Length)
            'COPY THE DATA TO THE MEMORY LOCATION
            Marshal.Copy(My.Resources.Monotype_Corsiva, 0, fontMemPointer, My.Resources.Monotype_Corsiva.Length)
            'LOAD THE MEMORY FONT INTO THE PRIVATE FONT COLLECTION
            _pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontMemPointer, My.Resources.Monotype_Corsiva.Length)
            'FREE UNSAFE MEMORY
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontMemPointer)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ERROR LOADING FONT. HANDLE EXCEPTION HERE
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Function IsFontInstalled(ByVal font As String) As Boolean
        Dim FontCollection = New InstalledFontCollection
        Dim Result As Boolean = False
        For Each FontFamily In FontCollection.Families
            If FontFamily.Name = font Then
                Result = True
            End If
        Next
        Return Result
    End Function
End Module
```

So is it possible to install the font permanently? This code seems like it installs the font but just to be used in the current session. If the unit is restarted, the font will no longer be usable.

I just want to speed up the startup of my program.

Comment: There is no api for that, only an installer can add fonts.  Or the Fonts applet in Control Panel.  Do beware the nasty bug in the code snippet, calling Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() is only valid *after* the PrivateFontCollection object is disposed.  The memory corruption doesn't crash a program nearly often enough.

Comment: @HansPassant So to prevent it from happening, I will move that code to the event closing of my application? Is that what you mean?

Comment: If that's the next logical place to put that call then you might as well not bother at all.  Not uncommon.